# Calling a function before declaring its body in python 3.x

Tags: python, function

I know that in python, all functions must be defined before any are used. So this code will result in an error:

```
hello()
def hello():
    print('Hi!')
```

But in a code like the one bellow:

```
def func():
    hello()

def hello():
    print('Hi!')

func()
```

The hello() function is called by func() before it's defined  and it still works and I don't understand why.

So can you please explain the above behavior and thanks in advance.

Comment: The function must be defined at *call time*, not at *definition time* of other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language, therefore it is interpreted line by line,

Both your examples follow the same logic,

in the second one,

`func` and `hello` have already been interpreted, so when you call `func()` they both are known and for that executed.

```
def func():
    hello()
```

--> At this level func is known but not executed (called) yet

```
def hello():
    print('Hi!')
```

--> At this level, both func and hello are known but not executed (called) yet

```
func()
```

--> Finally when you call `func`, no matter what order `func` and `hello` are. They are known and have an address in memory.

Comment: @user3885884 sure ! you may mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Defining a new function does not execute it. Hence the `hello()` function is only called when you call `func()`, which is done after defining `hello()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because Python code is parsed top-down, and whenever the interpreter sees a function call, *it has to execute it right away*, so if it's not defined (yet), this will be an error.

On the other hand, if this function isn't being called now, but the call appears in a definition of another function, the interpreter 'says': "Okay, there *should* be a function called `hello`, so I'm gonna look for it". If it does find it, it's OK, otherwise it's an error.